# Animation for $\mathbb{T}= \mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$

Tags: general-topology

Does someone could explain to me (with animation in 2-D if possible) why could we express the torus as $\mathbb{T}= \mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ (with $\Gamma = \text{(identity matrix)} \mathbb{Z}^n$)? The problem is pretty clear when I look at the circle $\mathbb{T}= \mathbb{R}/2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$, but when we observe in higher dimension, the problem becomes hard to imagine.

Comment: If it's clear in 1-D it should be clear in 2-D since a torus is the product of two circles. So the (usual) torus is the plane mod the integer lattice. For higher dimensions you have to use your imagination :-)

Comment: Look at the coloring a torus on the [Torus wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Coloring_a_torus) it shows first getting to a cylinder and then to a 2-torus.

Comment: When we quotient $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\Gamma$, I would like to know what it represents on the torus with different matrices $A$ for $\Gamma = A \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: What does it mean by $\Gamma=I\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: By the way why is the tag "spectral-graph-theory"? Any background from that field? Looks like topology for me.

Comment: Not an animation, but the image from my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1708176/86418) to [“Natural” example of cosets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706973) may be of interest.